# Why doesn't footer text expand to same length as text at very bottom?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a site for my school website and have been running into multiple footer problems. While most problems, seem to have been fixed, I do have one concern: the footer is split into two parts, an upper and a lower. While the lower text is stretched to the desired width, I am unable to reproduce the effect on the upper portion of the footer so that all text is aligned at the same level. I have uploaded an example of the template at http://test.victoriaparkci.com/tpl2/ but I believe that the problem lies somewhere in the site's [CSS](http://test.victoriaparkci.com/tpl2/style.css). Please help if you can.

Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks, changing margin and padding fixed the problem.

Comment: The upper text where it says "About VPCI" and such was not aligning with the "Credits" text at the bottom. While that has been fixed, I would also like the content that I would put in the calendar area to align to the copyright notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because the upper part uses *ul* tag, which is unordered list, and this list has a "respectively" large indent. You will need to use something like this to remove the indent:

```
ul {
    padding: value1;
    margin: value2;
}

ul li {
    padding: value3;
    margin: value4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, changing the padding has fixed the left side of the problem. Is there any way the same can be done so stuff inserted below the calendar text can align to the right?